# How to make my template made with the bootrap grid system printable

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, bootstrap-5

I am developing a template to load data and then print it, but the grid system does not respect my columns, does anyone know any technique so that they can be ordered and how?

I attach part of my code bellow.

```
    <div class="container-fluid mt-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <div class="row ms-4">
                    <!-- Head -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="logo_mb_i.svg" alt="logo" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-7 text-end">
                                Número identificador: {{user.id}}<br>
                                Fecha de consulta: {{user.date_consult}}<br>
                                Nombre: {{user.name}} {{user.surname}} {{user.second_surname}}<br>
                                RFC: {{user.rfc}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Head -->

                    <!-- Body -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 mt-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div id="myChart" class="chart--container">
                                    <a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com/">Powered by ZingChart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9 mt-16">
                                FICO SCORE RANGO </br>
                                549
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 align-items-center">
                                <h3>Datos generales</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisa</p>
                                <p></p></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                Nombre(s)</br>
                                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                RFC</br>
                                <p>lorem</p>
                                Email:</br>
                                <p>lorem@gmail.com</p>
                                Domicilio:</br>
                                <p>lorem32, col. lorem La lorem,</p></br>
                                <p>lorem, MX.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                Fecha de nacimiento:</br>
                                <p>lorem lorem lorem</p>
                                CURP:</br>
                                <p>lorem</p>
                                Teléfono:</br>
                                <p>3333333333</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Body -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <!-- right side indicators -->
                <div class="row right-side">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h6 class="vertical-text">lorem</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- right side indicators -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So if anyone knows how to do it, I will be eternally grateful, the truth is that I am lost in the construction of my pdf.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: bootstrap column are 12, but all add. So with 12 item in the same line, each will be `col-sm-1`. Also, what do you want exactly ?

Comment: I would like to print my entire design with my columns, but when I print them the order changes

Comment: How are you printing them ? Can you include it in your question ?

Comment: Sure, I'll attach it.